# Chooser does not open video

Tags: java

package asd;

import com.sun.jna.Native;

import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class VLCPlayer {

public static void main(final String[] args) {

NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\Program

Files\VideoLAN\VLC");

Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

@Override

public void run() {

new VLCPlayer(args);

}

});

}

private VLCPlayer(String[] args) {

JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

URL mediaUrl=null;

try {

mediaUrl = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toURI().toURL();

} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

.out.println(ex);

}

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Видео ойнатқыш"); 
MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();

Canvas c = new Canvas();

c.setBackground(Color.black);

JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

p.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);

EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = 
mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();

mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));

frame.setLocation(100, 100);

frame.setSize(1050, 600);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

frame.setVisible(true);

mediaPlayer.playMedia("D:\film1.avi");

}

}

Comment: First, can you [edit] to format your code using the `{}` button, the code is unreadable. Then, can you explain what is the problem ? You might check again [ask] to give us a description of what you want and what is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your code, but I see that you have hardcoded the value in
`mediaPlayer.playMedia("D:\film1.avi");`

I think you want to use
`mediaPlayer.playMedia(mediaUrl);`